# How to determine the unitary transformation from atomic orbitals to symmetry-adapted atomic orbitals of Ethylene

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am trying to find the unitary transformation matrix **U** from the atomic orbitals $|\mathbf{\chi}\rangle$ of ethylene to the symmetry-adapted atomic orbitals $|\mathbf{\chi}'\rangle$ of Ethylene, i.e $|\mathbf{\chi}'\rangle = |\mathbf{\chi}\rangle \mathbf{U}$.

Now, I've concluded that $\Gamma = A_g + B_{1g} + B_{2u} + B_{3u}$ for the hydrogen atomic orbitals $\{\chi^H_i\}_{i=1}^4$ and my line of thinking is now that given the ordering of the AOs :$|\mathbf{\chi}\rangle = [\chi_{1s}^{H1}$, $\chi_{1s}^{H2}$, $\chi_{1s}^{H3}$, $\chi_{1s}^{H4}$
$\chi_{1s}^{C1}$, $\chi_{2s}^{C1}$, $\chi_{1s}^{C2}$, $\chi_{2s}^{C2}$
$\chi_{2py}^{C1}$, $\chi_{2py}^{C2}$, $\chi_{2pz}^{C1}$, $\chi_{2pz}^{C2}$, $\chi_{2px}^{C1}$, $\chi_{2px}^{C2}$] the 14x14 unitary matrix $\mathbf{U}$ should be of the form:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{U} = \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}, \text{ } A = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
A_g & B_{1g} & B_{2u} & B_{3u}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & -1 &-1\\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} ,
\end{equation}
and the rest of  $\mathbf{U} \text{ is diagonal of 1.}$

In this way, to my understanding, the hydrogen atomic orbitals will be symmetry-adapted after transformation by $\mathbf{U}$ but do I also need to consider the carbon orbitals? I.e is the rest of $\mathbf{U}$ not as simple as I believe or is $\mathbf{U}$ found by some other process?